# Hide TextField selection handles

Tags: dart, flutter

Im my application when the user selects a TextField the existing text gets automatically selected when the Focus changes to the textfield. How do I hide the blue selection handles that appear?

The reason I want to automatically select the existing text is so that the user can begin typing and the textfield will automatically overwrite the existing value instead of appending to it.

[image]

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. You can set the `enableInteractiveSelection` property to false.

Comment: Not only does this hide the handles but also disables any kind of interaction.

Comment: TexzField onT:ap: no longer works with enableInteractiveSelection set to false !